# Can't POST/GET/PUT anything after deploying - runs fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, mern

I'm very new so sorry about this...

Basically, I am trying to replicate a blog from a youtube tutorial - however there was nothing available on how to deploy the application so I'm trying to replicate it as much as I can.

I successfully deployed both the backend and frontend separately on render, then I changed the axios URL to link with the backend. I then type the backend URL with /api/posts and it retrieves the posts in the DB so I am not sure what else I am missing out on if someone could help me that would be great.

[Frontend](https://github.com/KJafro/pld)
[Backend](https://github.com/KJafro/deploying)

Ignore the added extra frontend folder in the backend folder as that was an accident... If that has an effect on this?

Thank you.

ERROR: everydaybeing.onrender.com/auth/register:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tried to link the frontend to backend but unsuccessful

Comment: Are you able to hit this URL from postman?

Comment: No, cannot GET route but I don't know why... It works when I change all of the axios URLs to localhost and I am able to GET/POST/PUT everything but soon as I change all the URLs from localhost to my render URL it won't work :( sorry I am new to this so it might be me being stupid

Comment: This is quite possibly a deployment issue since you are saying everything is working fine in localhost. Try to produce the server logs from onrender so that I can troubleshoot more. Besides tag onreder in the question so that people know it could be deployment issue.